# What exactly is the Game in Herman Hesse's The Glass Bead Game?

Tags: the-glass-bead-game

Is it a fictional version of Leibniz's universal language? It seems to be a physically played game, so I'm curious as to how it would work, since any real world attempt was paper-based. Did he ever expand on it or did anyone else try to craft something fitting?

Comment: A bunch of people have created their own (headcanon) versions; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Glass_Bead_Game#External_links

Comment: Note that a similar question could be asked about [Azad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Player_of_Games#Azad) with about as much success.

Comment: Thanks  I somehow didn't see any of these